# Byte array cryptography in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

I want to create a nice cryptography using bitwise operators.
However I fail to do so.

I want it to have bitwise operators using a byte array to encrypt and decrypt my byte array.

```
public class Cryptographer
{
    private byte[] Keys { get; set; }

    public Cryptographer(string password)
    {
        Keys = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
    }

    public void Encrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte) (data[i] & Keys[i]);
        }
    }

    public void Decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte)(Keys[i] & data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong, thats why I need help.
I simply want it to use 1 string to encrypt and decrypt all data.

Comment: Telling what is holding you back helps other people help you.

Comment: What is holding me back is I find the operators very hard to understand, and also I don't know a technique to make this cryptography a bit more secure.

Comment: If you are serious about using this to protect anything, you are ill-advised to write your own code here.  If this is practice code, then fine.

Comment: Note edit regarding DPAPI which may give you what you need

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is what is sometimes known as 'craptography', because it provides the illusion of security while being functionally useless in protecting anything.  Use the [framework classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) if you want to do cryptography right, because it's extremely difficult to roll your own.

Take a look at this for advice on what you are trying to do (encrypt/decrypt) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e970bs09.aspx. Really your requirements should determine what classes you decide to use. This has good background: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92f9ye3s.aspx

For simple encrypt/decrypt (if this is what you need) [DPAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/05/126825.aspx) may be the simplest way.

Comment: I do not know a lot about cryptography, and I certainly do not know how to implement them.

Comment: @Basser You don't need to "implement" the framework classes. You just need to click the link.

Comment: @bzlm, I've never used one of those classes, I will need to set them up correctly and secure.

Comment: @Basser You sure will. Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry if post seems harsh but this is a certifiably 'hard problem' that is being continually worked on by people (good guys and bad guys) way smarter than you or me, hence writing your own is not advisable.

Comment: Which cryptography is the easiest to use to your opinion, I really doubt I will get them working correctly.

Comment: Take a look at this for advice on what you need to do - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e970bs09.aspx.  Really your requirements should determine what classes you decide to use.  This has good background: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92f9ye3s.aspx

Comment: @Basser: The only security mechanism that I'm aware of that is easy to get right is SSL/TLS ( [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) ). Any homegrown mechanism that combines popular algorithms like AES, SHA-1 from   the System.Security.Cryptography Namespace is a placebo at best and a danger at worst.

Comment: While I agree that using some cryptography framework is best for real-world scenarios, I believe OP was trying to learn basic cryptography and the only good way to learn it is to start from the beginning and roll your own simple xor code. Thats exactly how i just found this post, trying to learn simple xor for learning purposes. I would never write my own for my sensitive data.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be trying to implement the [XOR cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). XOR is `^`  in C#:

```
public void Crypt(byte[] data)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (byte) (data[i] ^ Keys[i]);
    }                             ↑
}
```

Since the Encrypt and Decrypt method do exactly the same, you need only one method.

Note, however, that this is just a toy and **not suitable** to secure data in real-world scenarios. Have a look at the [System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) which provides many implementations of proven algorithms. Using these correctly is still **hard to get right** though.

Comment: A (silly) nitpick: XOR encryption can be secure if *(a)* the key is at least as long as the message, *(b)* the key is truly random, and *(c)* the key is never re-used. Voila! A one-time pad.

Answer (score 6):

Use Xor `^` operator and not And `&`. Also you should not assume that data and key are the same length.

```
public class Cryptographer
{
    private byte[] Keys { get; set; }

    public Cryptographer(string password)
    {
        Keys = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
    }

    public void Encrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte) (data[i] ^ Keys[i % Keys.Length]);
        }
    }

    public void Decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte)(Keys[i % Keys.Length] ^ data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want it to be a bit more advanced, and I am really confused right now.

Comment: Check this for example code of using .Net classes for encryption:  http://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=EncryptionCS&Title=Symmetric%20Key%20Encryption&Lang=C%23

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Int32 a = 138;
        Console.WriteLine("first int: " + a.ToString());

        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);

        var bits = new BitArray(bytes);
        String lol = ToBitString(bits);
        Console.WriteLine("bit int: " + lol);

        lol = lol.Substring(1, lol.Length - 1) + lol[0];
        Console.WriteLine("left   : " + lol);

        byte[] bytes_new = GetBytes(lol);

        byte[] key = { 12, 13, 24, 85 };
        var bits2 = new BitArray(key);
        String lol2 = ToBitString(bits2);
        Console.WriteLine("key    : " + lol2);

        byte[] cryptedBytes = Crypt(bytes_new, key);
        var bits3 = new BitArray(cryptedBytes);
        String lol3 = ToBitString(bits3);
        Console.WriteLine("    XOR: " + lol3);

        byte[] deCryptedBytes = Crypt(cryptedBytes, key);
        var bits4 = new BitArray(cryptedBytes);
        String lol4 = ToBitString(bits4);
        Console.WriteLine("  DEXOR: " + lol4);

        int a_new = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes_new, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("and int: " + a_new.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static byte[] Crypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
    {
        byte[] toCrypt = data;
        for (int i = 0; i < toCrypt.Length; i++)
        {
            toCrypt[i] = (byte)(toCrypt[i] ^ key[i]);
        }
        return toCrypt;
    }

    private static String ToBitString(BitArray bits)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = bits.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char c = bits[i] ? '1' : '0';
            sb.Append(c);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static byte[] GetBytes(string bitString)
    {
        byte[] result = Enumerable.Range(0, bitString.Length / 8).
            Select(pos => Convert.ToByte(
                bitString.Substring(pos * 8, 8),
                2)
            ).ToArray();

        List<byte> mahByteArray = new List<byte>();
        for (int i = result.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            mahByteArray.Add(result[i]);
        }

        return mahByteArray.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, there is no such thing as a 'secure' cipher. Any encryption method that can be written can be broken.
With that being said, using simple bitwise techniques for encryption is inviting a not too bright hacker to break your encryption. There are guys/gals that sit around all day long with nothing better to do.
Use one of the encryption libraries that uses a large key and do something 'unusual' to that key before using it. Even so, remember, there are people employed and not employed to do nothing but break cryptographic messages all around the world; 24 by 7.
The Germans thought they had an un-breakable system in WW II. They called it Enigma. Do some reading on it and you will discover that it was broken even before the war broke out!