# String substitution (C#)

Tags: c#

Programming in c#.
I'm trying to substitute every char in a string with another char (Encryption), but I need some help. I was going to do this using two arrays, one with the alphabet in it, then the other with the substitute values, but I realized I'd have to do a else-if the size of the whole alphabet, which I don't really have time for. I'd like to know if there is an easier, faster way. This is what I have so far

```
private string EncryptFn(string Sinput)
{
    string STencryptedResult = "Null for now";
    char[] CAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    char[] Encrypt = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM".ToCharArray();

    return STencryptedResult;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there a limited number of characters in your input string?

Comment: But your `CAlphabet` only handles 'A' through 'Z'. What happens to the other characters?

Comment: I only intended it to encrypt alphabet chars, not numbers and special characters, etc.

Comment: Why do people just down-vote questions or answers without giving an explanation?

Comment: ..is there any reason you're not using a built in encryption provider?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the encryption provider (System.Security.Cryptography?) - if you could help me to use it, or give me an example, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What you're doing right now is **not** encryption. At best, it's a cypher.

Comment: You could just Base64 encode the string. It probably wouldn't be a lot less secure that straight character swapping.

Comment: @DeanOC Base64 would be the same thing, except the cypher code is known so there is no difficulty in decoding.  The OP's solution is much better then Base64, but both solutions do not perform good encryption.

Comment: You should share your end goal with us FrodoBaggins. If this is a homework assignment, the solutions currently provided are appropriate. If this is for storing a password securely, you won't want to encrypt them, you'll want to hash them. If this is for sending secret messages to your friend, there are appropriate solutions for that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a very strong encryption, but you the following version would be extremely efficient and requires very little data to define the encryption:

```
private string EncryptFn(string Sinput)
{
    string coding = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in Sinput)
    {
        int index = (Char.ToUpper(c) - 'A');
        if (index >= 0 && index < coding.Length)
            result.Append(coding[index]);
        else
            result.Append(c);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: ` int index = (c.ToUpper() - 'A');` causes an error No overload for method 'ToUpper' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Thanks, Marked as an answer!

Comment: No, you marked Andrew's reply as an answer. That's fine, but I would expect mine to outperform his code and the declaration requires much less typing.

Comment: Oh, I tried to mark two, sorry :P. I prefer your answer, personally, but wanted to give him some credit as well.

Comment: I don't mind which gets marked as the correct answer as they both give the desired result. About the performance though, I tried a little benchmarking (1000000 iterations of each solution) and found that the use of Char.ToUpper() almost doubles the run time and makes this solution slower than the dictionary lookup. Micro-optimisations FTW! ;]

Comment: Yes, I did make the assumption that he would also want to encrypt lower case characters, which your code didn't address. That is surprisingly slower though. I suspect because of Unicode. (And I don't mind which gets marked either.)

Answer (score 6):

You could use a Dictionary:

```
var map = new Dictionary<char,char> {
  { 'A', 'Q' },
  { 'B', 'W' },
  // etc
};
```

Then it becomes pretty easy to map each char with something like this:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach( var fromChar in inputString ) {
  char toChar;
  if( ! map.TryGetValue(fromChar, out toChar) ) {
    // Do something with missing char
  }
  result.Append(toChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider BitWise operations, they work great for encrypting and decrypting data. See the following.

[Byte array cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710132/byte-array-cryptography-in-c-sharp)